# Linux: start Android SDK or Android Emulator

Tags: android, linux, fedora, android-sdk-2.3

I'm using Linux (fedora 16). I try to install Android SDK and ADT. Each time I want to run `Android SDK` or `Android Emulator`, I must run from Eclipse, but I don't know how run directly. (don't need to open Eclipse)

In Windows, in AndroidSDK folder has file exe so you can run directly such as `AVD Manager.exe` or `SDK Manager.exe` but not in Linux.

Please help me about this issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to add the location (folder) in the android sdk which contains the tools on linux to the `PATH` so that you can launch android tools from terminal w/o eclipse

Comment: Yes. I have add this folder to Path. I add three folder to Path: androidSDK, androidSDK/tools and androidSDK/platform. But how can I run from console. (in androidSDK folder, there no file !!!)

Comment: What do you see in androidSDK/tools? In the newer version there is a single `android` executable which is both SDK & AVD manager. Maybe you can try just `android`

Comment: Oh. I have solved this problem. Unlike in Windows, `android emulator` and `android sdk` in Tools folder. thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the following commands , this should work if you have installed the sdk correctly

1. Open a terminal
2. su
3. input your password
4. cd Android/SDK/tools (enter)
5. ./emulator -noaudio @android_dev

Answer (score 10):

You can launch android SDK manager by simply moving to android-sdk/tools folder and using the following command:

```
./android &
```

To launch the emulator, from the same folder you need to execute the following command:

```
./emulator -avd youravdname
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to store Android SDK in `/opt/` and just run:
`$ sudo /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android`

You can add & at end to run it as background process.